# UV-unwrap to same position, scale and rotation as before?

Tags: uv

I have a mesh that had been UV-unwrapped and positioned on an image texture where I want it. I did some adjustments to the shape of the mesh, and that malformed the texture a bit. So I wanted to unwrap it again to get the correct shape, but in doing so the UV map is reset to the standard scale, position and rotation.

How can I UV-unwrap, but keep the scale, position and rotation? The reason I need to do this is that I have several similar images, and the position of the texture needs to be the same, even though the shape of the objects are a bit different.

I am in Blender 2.8 beta.

Thanks!